# Can Octave call external libraries (binary) the way matlab can?

Tags: linux, matlab, shared-libraries, octave, loadlibrary

I am thinking about port some of my matlab (on windows) applications to linux, the application is integrated in matlab on Windows, it will call some external library routine (I mean DLL, not .mex files) thourgh matlab's calllib routine.

However due to the expensive license fee, I want to port this to Octave in Linux, I just want to make sure the Octave can handle the external binary libaries just as well as Matlab (My application seldom use matlab toolbox so the lack of certain toolboxes on Octave should not be a problem for me).

Answer (score 3):

Last I checked, Octave did not implement the [`loadlibrary`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html) family of functions.

That doesn't mean you can't interface with this external library; you could always write a MEX/OCT wrapper function and call the library in your C/C++ code (I'm assuming this library has been ported to Linux in the first place!).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a DLL is incompatible to linux. Your application will not run on linux, neither with matlab nor with octave.

Comment: I think OP mentioned DLL in the sense that it is a shared library (.dll on Windows, .so on Linux, .dylib on OSX)